# Name 'listadj' is not defined

Tags: python, error-handling

Currently working on a mad libs program and everything is good until the end because it doesn't think the strings are defined. Any reason why it might be doing this? I have been trying to a while and nothing really seems to work. (There are other definitions for adj and verb etc. but it was too long, theyre identical to nounfind)

```
def nounfind():
    global nouncount
    print("Welcome to Mad Libs! Please proceed with the following steps.")
    nounstr = input("Separated by a comma AND A SPACE, list 8 nouns: ")
    listnoun = nounstr.split(", ")
    nouncount = 0
    for element in listnoun:
        nouncount += 1
    print("list:", listnoun)
    'finds value based on index number'
while nouncount == 0:
    nounfind()
while nouncount < 8:
    input("Incorrect input. Please press enter to try again.")
    nounfind()
while nouncount > 8:
    input("Incorrect input. Please press enter to try again.")
    nounfind()


adj1 = random.choice(listadj)
noun1 = random.choice(listnoun)
verb1 = random.choice(listverb)
prep1 = random.choice(listprep)
adj2 = random.choice(listadj)
noun2 = random.choice(listnoun)
adverb1 = random.choice(listadverb)
verb2 = random.choice(listverb)
verb3 = random.choice(listverb)
prep2 = random.choice(listprep)
adj3 = random.choice(listadj)
noun3 = random.choice(listnoun)

print("Poem Generated below!")
print("A/An", adj1, noun1, "\n")
print("A/An", adj1, noun1, verb1, prep1, "the", adj2, noun2)
print(adverb1, "the", noun1, verb2)
print("the", noun2, verb3, prep2, "a", adj3, noun3)
```

Comment: as the error message says: you never define `listadj`. also `listnoun` is only defined inside the function `nounfind`.

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful if you provided the following to help us understand your question better: 1) The actual error message shown, 2) The Output you are getting, and 3) The output you expect.